# How to proper use Ajax in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm a React JS newbie, I have this code that creates an `app` div with some `MusicPlayer` tag elements:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <MusicPlayer
                    id="2"
                    visualizerType="RIPPLES"
                    theme={darkTheme}
                    trackInfo={{
                        title: "Imitosis",
                            artist: "Andrew Bird",
                                album: "Armchair Apocrypha"
                    }}
                    trackUrl="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/teddarcuri.monarch/Andrew+Bird+-+Imitosis.mp3"
                    albumArt="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/teddarcuri.monarch/andrew+bird.jpg"
                    utilities={true}>
                </MusicPlayer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

**UPDATE**

[Based on this pen](http://codepen.io/teddarcuri/pen/EKWMvE)

Let's say I want to replace the `<MusicPlayer>` with this:

```
<MusicPlayer
    id="3"
    visualizerType="RIPPLES"
    theme={lightTheme}
    trackInfo={{
        title: "Guns & Dogs",
            artist: "Portugal, The Man",
                album: "The Satanic Satanist"
    }}
    trackUrl="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/teddarcuri.monarch/Portugal.+The+Man+-+Guns+%26+Dogs+-+The+Satanic+Satanist.mp3"
    albumArt="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61X7CiBpZ6L.jpg"
    utilities={true}>
</MusicPlayer>
```

How can this be done via Ajax?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PraneshRavi I need to understand how can I remove the MusicPlayer and add a new one via post Ajax. It's not clear to me how can I proceed after the render.

Comment: What does **new one** mean? Another MusicPlayer?

Comment: @PraneshRavi Yes, the MusicPlayer is a music player card and I would like to change it on click

Comment: Change to what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use React's `state`and `setState` to re-render the component with the new data. Call `setState` inside the ajax success callback and pass the new data to `setState`. This will render the `MusicPlayer` with the new data.

Hope this helps!

Pseudo code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { //initial empty details
      details : {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //place the ajax call where ever you need
    $.ajax() //call ajax
    .done((data) => {
      this.setState({ //this setState will re render the UI with the new state
        details: { //change the key value pairs as needed
          id: data.id,
          trackInfo: {
            title: data.title,
            artist: data.artist,
            album: data.album,
          },
          trackUrl: data.trackUrl,
          albumArt: data.albumArt,
        }
      })
    })
  }
    render() {
      if(!this.state.details.id) return false //renders nothing when no details available
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <MusicPlayer
                    id={this.state.details.id}
                    visualizerType="RIPPLES"
                    theme={darkTheme}
                    trackInfo={this.state.details.trackInfo}
                    trackUrl={this.state.details.trackUrl}
                    albumArt={this.state.details.albumArt}
                    utilities={true}>
                </MusicPlayer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

*Ps. Frequency bars looks better than frequency ripples :P*

Comment: @SimonLeCat No problems. I really liked the frequency bars. Go luck with that!

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code (unknown: Unexpected token), please double check `details = {}`

Comment: @SimonLeCat That's a good question. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ this should help you to understand jQuery. If you need further assistance you could raise a new question tagging jQuery.

Comment: Yes. A JSON containing all the required information